I have this error code is arm_cmplx_mag. the error says undefined. I already include the library
I have this error. one of my snippet code is arm_cmplx_mag. the error says undefined. I already include the library the directories where the arm_cortexM4lf_math is. I also included directly my arm_const_structs.h and my arm_math.h. so what seems to be my problem.
I havent tried anything cuz i might mess up my code
